# How to average at two levels?

Tags: sqlite, group-by, average

I am trying to average at multiple levels but am able to for one level only:

```
SELECT group_id,
STRFTIME("%W", date) as week_num,
AVG(count_value) as value FROM counts
GROUP BY week_num;
```

I get:

[image]

How to get averages for each `group_id` based on average of each `week_num`? I have to calculate average at **week_num** level and then average at `group_id` level. Expected result:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: group by group_id only.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to calculate averages at week_num level and then calculate the average at group_id level in the outer query:

```
SELECT group_id, AVG(value)
FROM (
    SELECT group_id,
           STRFTIME("%W", date) as week_num,
           AVG(count_value) as value FROM counts
    GROUP BY group_id, week_num
)
GROUP BY group_id;
```